# Why android ViewPager OnTouchListener not called at all

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

Why my ViewPager `OnTouchListener` doesn't fire at all !!

Here is my code below:

I'm using `ViewPager` to automatically slide photos but when i tap on the `ViewPager` I need to stop the auto sliding but the problem is that my `OnTouchListener` doesn't fire at all.

**JAVA**

**man_fragment.java**

```
package com.techzone.yallaassouk;

/**
 * Created by Yazan on 4/26/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.techzone.yallaassouk.Adapters.Brands_View_Adapter;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.Adapters.Categories_View_Adapter;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.Adapters.ImageSlideAdapter;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.DataItems.Band;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.DataItems.Brand;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.DataItems.Category;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.Utils.CirclePageIndicator;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.Utils.PageIndicator;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.Utils.CheckNetworkConnection;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.json.GetJSONObject;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.json.JsonReader;


import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.List;

public class man_fragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "man_fragment";

    private static final long ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY = 5000;
    private static final long ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY_USER_VIEW = 10000;
    private static final int TabNo = 1;

    // UI References
    ViewPager BandsViewPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;
    RecyclerView brands_Rec_View;
    RecyclerView categories_Rec_View;

    //lists
    List<Band> bands;
    List<Brand> brands;
    List<Category> categories;

    //tasks
    RequestBandsTask bands_task;
    RequestBrandsTask brands_task;
    RequestCategoriesTask categories_task;

    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    boolean stopSliding = false;
    String message;

    //lists adapters
    Brands_View_Adapter brands_adapter;
    Categories_View_Adapter categories_adapter;

    //runnables and handlers
    private Runnable animateViewPager;
    private Handler handler;

    //urls
    String brandsurl = "http://yazanallahham-001-site1.ftempurl.com/Brands.svc/json/brands/"+TabNo;
    String categoriesurl = "http://yazanallahham-001-site1.ftempurl.com/categories.svc/json/categories/"+TabNo+"/0";
    String bandsurl = "http://yazanallahham-001-site1.ftempurl.com/bands.svc/json/bands/0";

    //activity
    FragmentActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.man_fragment, container, false);

        findViewById(rootView);

        mIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageChangeListener());
        BandsViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageChangeListener());
        BandsViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        stopSliding = true;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // calls when touch release on ViewPager
                        if (bands != null && bands.size() != 0) {
                            stopSliding = false;
                            runnable(bands.size());
                            handler.postDelayed(animateViewPager,
                                    ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY_USER_VIEW);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        // calls when ViewPager touch
                        if (handler != null && stopSliding == false) {
                            stopSliding = true;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(animateViewPager);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

//        sendRequest();

        //init brands recyclerview
        brands_Rec_View.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        brands_Rec_View.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this.getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        categories_fragment nextFrag= new categories_fragment();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        Brand clickedBrand = (Brand)brands.get(position);
                        args.putInt("BrandId", clickedBrand.getId());
                        args.putInt("TabId", TabNo);
                        args.putString("BrandName", clickedBrand.getEnName());
                        nextFrag.setArguments(args);
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.main_content, nextFrag, categories_fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                                .addToBackStack(categories_fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                                .commit();
                    }
                })
        );

        //init categories recyclerview
        GridLayoutManager LLM =  new GridLayoutManager(activity, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false){
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollVertically(){
                return false;
            }
        };
        categories_Rec_View.setLayoutManager(LLM);
        categories_Rec_View.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this.getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //Log.d("categories","test click" + position);
                        Items_fragment nextFrag= new Items_fragment();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        Category clickedCategory = (Category)categories.get(position);
                        args.putInt("CategoryId", clickedCategory.getId());
                        args.putString("CategoryName", clickedCategory.getEnName());
                        args.putInt("BrandId", 0);
                        args.putInt("TabId", TabNo);
                        nextFrag.setArguments(args);
                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.main_content, nextFrag, Items_fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                                .addToBackStack(Items_fragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)
                                .commit();
                    }
                })
        );
        return rootView;
    }

    private void findViewById(View view) {
        BandsViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.man_view_pager);
        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        brands_Rec_View = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.brands_RView);
        categories_Rec_View = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.categories_RView);
    }

    public void runnable(final int size) {
        handler = new Handler();
        animateViewPager = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!stopSliding) {
                    if (BandsViewPager.getCurrentItem() == size - 1) {
                        BandsViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    } else {
                        BandsViewPager.setCurrentItem(
                                BandsViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(animateViewPager, ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);
                }
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (bands == null) {
            sendRequest();
        } else {
            BandsViewPager.setAdapter(new ImageSlideAdapter(activity, bands,
                    man_fragment.this));
            mIndicator.setViewPager(BandsViewPager);
            runnable(bands.size());
            //Re-run callback
            handler.postDelayed(animateViewPager, ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);
        }
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (bands_task != null)
            bands_task.cancel(true);
        if (handler != null) {
            //Remove callback
            handler.removeCallbacks(animateViewPager);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        if (CheckNetworkConnection.isConnectionAvailable(activity)) {
            bands_task = new RequestBandsTask(activity);
            bands_task.execute(bandsurl);

            brands_task = new RequestBrandsTask(activity);
            brands_task.execute(brandsurl);

            categories_task = new RequestCategoriesTask(activity);
            categories_task.execute(categoriesurl);
        } else {
            message = getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection);
            showAlertDialog(message, true);
        }
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(String message, final boolean finish) {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if (finish)
                            activity.finish();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class PageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (bands != null) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private class RequestBandsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Band>> {
        private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;
        Throwable error;

        public RequestBandsTask(Activity context) {
            this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Band> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = getJsonObject(urls[0]);
                if (jsonObject != null) {
//                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonObject
//                            .getJSONObject(TagName.TAG_BRANDS);
//                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                        bands = JsonReader.getBands(jsonObject);

//                    } else {
//                        message = jsonObject.getString(TagName.TAG_BRANDS);
//                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bands;
        }

        /**
         * It returns jsonObject for the specified url.
         *
         * @param url
         * @return JSONObject
         */
        public JSONObject getJsonObject(String url) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = GetJSONObject.getJSONObject(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Band> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (activityWeakRef != null && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
                if (error != null && error instanceof IOException) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.time_out);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else if (error != null) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.error_occured);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else {
                    bands = result;
                    if (result != null) {
                        if (bands != null && bands.size() != 0) {
                            //for brands_adapter
                            BandsViewPager.setAdapter(new ImageSlideAdapter(
                                    activity, bands, man_fragment.this));

                            mIndicator.setViewPager(BandsViewPager);
                            runnable(bands.size());
                            handler.postDelayed(animateViewPager,
                                    ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);

                        } else {
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class RequestBrandsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Brand>> {
        private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;
        Throwable error;

        public RequestBrandsTask(Activity context) {
            this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Brand> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = getJsonObject(urls[0]);
                if (jsonObject != null) {
//                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonObject
//                            .getJSONObject(TagName.TAG_BRANDS);
//                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                    brands = JsonReader.getBrands(jsonObject);

//                    } else {
//                        message = jsonObject.getString(TagName.TAG_BRANDS);
//                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return brands;
        }

        /**
         * It returns jsonObject for the specified url.
         *
         * @param url
         * @return JSONObject
         */
        public JSONObject getJsonObject(String url) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = GetJSONObject.getJSONObject(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Brand> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (activityWeakRef != null && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
                if (error != null && error instanceof IOException) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.time_out);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else if (error != null) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.error_occured);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else {
                    brands = result;
                    if (result != null) {
                        if (brands != null && brands.size() != 0) {
                            //for brands_adapter
                            brands_adapter = new Brands_View_Adapter(brands);
                            brands_Rec_View.setAdapter(brands_adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
                        } else {
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class RequestCategoriesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Category>> {
        private final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakRef;
        Throwable error;

        public RequestCategoriesTask(Activity context) {
            this.activityWeakRef = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Category> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = getJsonObject(urls[0]);
                if (jsonObject != null) {
//                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonObject
//                            .getJSONObject(TagName.TAG_BRANDS);
//                    if (jsonObject != null) {
                    categories = JsonReader.getCategories(jsonObject);

//                    } else {
//                        message = jsonObject.getString(TagName.TAG_BRANDS);
//                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return categories;
        }

        /**
         * It returns jsonObject for the specified url.
         *
         * @param url
         * @return JSONObject
         */
        public JSONObject getJsonObject(String url) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = GetJSONObject.getJSONObject(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Category> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (activityWeakRef != null && !activityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {
                if (error != null && error instanceof IOException) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.time_out);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else if (error != null) {
                    message = getResources().getString(R.string.error_occured);
                    showAlertDialog(message, true);
                } else {
                    categories = result;
                    if (result != null) {
                        if (categories != null && categories.size() != 0) {
                            //for brands_adapter

                            categories_adapter = new Categories_View_Adapter(categories);
                            categories_Rec_View.setAdapter(categories_adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
                            categories_Rec_View.getLayoutParams().height = (188*(categories_adapter.getItemCount()+1)+328);
                        } else {
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View Pager Adapter**

**ImageSlideAdapter.java**

```
package com.techzone.yallaassouk.Adapters;

/**
 * Created by Yazan on 5/1/2016.
 */

import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
        import java.util.List;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;

        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
        import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import com.techzone.yallaassouk.DataItems.Band;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.R;

import com.techzone.yallaassouk.TouchImageView;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.fragment.ProductDetailFragment;
import com.techzone.yallaassouk.man_fragment;
        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingListener;
        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
        import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;

public class ImageSlideAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoadingListener imageListener;
    FragmentActivity activity;
    List<Band> bands;
    Fragment homeFragment;
    public ImageSlideAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, List<Band> bands,
                             Fragment homeFragment) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.homeFragment = homeFragment;
        this.bands = bands;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.a1)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.a2)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.a3).cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc().build();

        imageListener = new ImageDisplayListener();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bands.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vp_image, container, false);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.image_display);

        imageLoader.displayImage(
                ((Band) bands.get(position)).getImageURL(), mImageView,
                options, imageListener);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    private static class ImageDisplayListener extends
            SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections
                .synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                                      Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for being not formatted. I'm new here

Comment: That's a lot of code, are you sure it can't be reduced? The longer it is, the less people will have a look at it...

Comment: @FabioTurati you are right!! I'm sorry...anyway I found the solution and I removed the huge code block :) 

Thank you

Comment: Great, but please, if you find a solution, don't edit it into the question (and especially do not remove the description of the problem from the question body); instead, post an answer. Answering your own questions is allowed, and even encouraged. And then, of course, you can mark it as accepted. This way it might be useful to others who could stumble onto this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @FabioTurati Again! I'm sorry :( I didn't know that! I will change it right now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was causing the 'ViewPager' not to fire 'OnTouchListener'

In layout **XML** file :

```
<com.techzone.yallaassouk.ExtendedViewPager
    android:id="@+id/man_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="137dp" />

<com.techzone.yallaassouk.Utils.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="130dp"/>
```

the problem was the 'paddingTop' of the 'CirclePageIndicator' it was set to '130dp' which covers the 'ViewPager' and it was receiving the touch events instead of 'ViewPager' itself.

Thank you.